# Windows Search Companion Results For Zip Files

Tags: zip, windows-search

Does anyone know if Windows Search Companion can show the filesystem path and/or actual filename of the zip file that contains the found result row?

If the zip file `C:\TEMP\Instance.zip` contains a file with internal path `\somepackage\somefile.txt`, I can see that the search results will show `\somepackage\somefile.txt` in the Windows Search Companion results column "In Folder".

I'm wondering if there is any way, using Windows Search Companion (with or without any software addon), to see that `\somepackage\somefile.txt` is actually compressed within `C:\TEMP\Instance.zip` i.e. to show `C:\TEMP` as the containing ("In Folder") folder and/or that `Instance.zip` is the containing zip file?